# how can i use Mongo db ssl connection with user auth in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when i used ssl connection with user auth in node.js + mongoose , i got error
            [MongoError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 closed]

```
 var o = {
    server: {
            auto_reconnect:true,
            sslValidate:true,
            sslCA: ca,
            sslKey: key,
            sslCert:cert,
            sslPass:'123@xyz' 
        }, 
        user: 'User',
        pass: 'xxx123xxx'
    };

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/collar',o);
```

please help me :(